# Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to System.Windows.Forms.Label

Tags: string, vb.net

I'm a bit of a noob. When I try to build my solution I get this single error and I don't know what to do to fix it.

```
 'Calculate and display cost estimate
                decCostEstimate = decFeet * decCostPerFoot
                **lblCostEstimate = decCostEstimate.ToString("C")**
```

I'm not sure what to do. Please help me.

Comment: If you use [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) then Visual Studio will tell you that something is wrong even before you get to the stage of trying to build the solution.

Comment: You can find this setting in 
Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults.
This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the Text property of the label, not the label itself

```
lblCostEstimate.Text = decCostEstimate.ToString("C")
```

Your code tries to assign a string value to an object of type Label, thus causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

The label is an object from the type  `Label`.
It is not possible to write an object from Type `int` or `string`, etc. into an label-object.

To make the label show your result just put the result into the text-property of the label:

`lblCostEstimate.Text = decCostEstimate.ToString("C")`